# Counting same length items in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to port a cgi script using pythonic style of coding.

```
sequence = "aaaabbababbbbabbabb"
res = sequence.split("a") + sequence.split("b")
res = [l for l in res if l]
```

The result is

```
>>> res
['bb', 'b', 'bbbb', 'bb', 'bb', 'aaaa', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

This was ~100loc in C. Now i want to count the items with the same length in the res list efficiently. For example here res contains 5 elements with length 1, 3 elements with length 2 and 2 elements with length 4.

The problem is that the sequence string can be very big.

Comment: Could you explain what your code does? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: You should note the output you want, e.g. the dictionary with numeric keys and values.

Comment: @Blender My code finds subsequences that have the same character. What I am asking here is a way to count how many times a sequence of length x exists in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to generate a histogram of string lengths given a list of strings is to use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = ["a", "b", "aaa", "bb", "aa", "bbb", "", "a", "b"]
>>> Counter(map(len, a))
Counter({1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2, 0: 1})
```

**Edit**: There is also a better way to find runs of equal characters, namely `itertools.groupby()`:

```
>>> sequence = "aaaabbababbbbabbabb"
>>> Counter(len(list(it)) for k, it in groupby(sequence))
Counter({1: 5, 2: 3, 4: 2})
```

Comment: I won't answer you comment. I will just accept this anwser as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like

```
occurrences_by_length={} # map of length of string->number of strings with that length.
for i in (len(x) for x in (sequence.split("a")+sequence.split("b"))):
    if i in occurrences_by_length:
        occurrences_by_length[i]=occurrences_by_length[i]+1
    else:
        occurrences_by_length[i]=1
```

Now occurrences_by_length has a mapping of the length of each string to the number of times a string of that length appears.

Comment: I usually find `for i in (something(x) for x in my_list)` quite awkward to read.  You can always translate this to `for x in my_list: i = something(x)`.